# Async Await in F#

Tags: .net, f#, async-await, c#-to-f#

I am rewriting some of the C# in this lab to F#: https://github.com/Microsoft/TechnicalCommunityContent/tree/master/IoT/Azure%20Stream%20Analytics/Session%202%20-%20Hands%20On

I am on Exercise 6, #17 - creating the `SimpleEventProcessor` type.
I want to implement the `CloseAsync` method

C#

```cs
async Task IEventProcessor.CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{0}', Reason: '{1}'.", context.Lease.PartitionId, reason);
        if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown)
        {
            await context.CheckpointAsync();
        }
    }
```

and I started like this:

```
member this.CloseAsync(context, reason) = 
    Debug.WriteLine("Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{0}', Reason: '{1}'.", context.Lease.PartitionId, reason)
    match reason with 
    | CloseReason.Shutdown -> await context.CheckpointAsync()
    | _ -> ()
```

but I have 2 questions:

1. How do I return await in F# world?
2. How do I return the NOT case -> C# just ignore that possibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If the value has type `Async<'T>`, you can just return it without any keyword. If it has type `Task` or `Task<'T>`, you can do `|> Async.AwaitTask`.
2. You can return `async { return () }`.

So you get this:

```
member this.CloseAsync(context, reason) = 
    Debug.WriteLine("Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{0}', Reason: '{1}'.", context.Lease.PartitionId, reason)
    match reason with 
    | CloseReason.Shutdown -> context.CheckpointAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    | _ -> async { return () }
```

Another possibility is to put the whole block in an `async` workflow, and use `return!` for 1 and `return` for 2:

```
member this.CloseAsync(context, reason) = 
    async {
        Debug.WriteLine("Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{0}', Reason: '{1}'.", context.Lease.PartitionId, reason)
        match reason with 
        | CloseReason.Shutdown -> return! context.CheckpointAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        | _ -> return ()
    }
```

In fact, using an async workflow allows you to drop the `()` case similarly to C#:

```
member this.CloseAsync(context, reason) = 
    async {
        Debug.WriteLine("Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{0}', Reason: '{1}'.", context.Lease.PartitionId, reason)
        if reason = CloseReason.Shutdown then
            return! context.CheckpointAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    }
```

Comment: the IEventProcessor CloseAsync returns a Task.  So | CloseReason.Shutdown -> context.CheckpointAsync()  works.  Need to figure out how to return a empty task

Comment: This did it:             match reason with 
            | CloseReason.Shutdown -> context.CheckpointAsync() 
            | _ -> Task.CompletedTask

Comment: Ah right sorry, I misread your question, somehow I thought you were converting from Task to Async in addition to going from C# to F#.

Comment: If you use F# async instead of Task, isn't the convention to name the method AsyncClose instead of CloseAsync?